# What does "netwide" mean in Netwide Assembler (NASM)?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I haven't been able to find anything that explains this name. I'm not even sure which 'net' is being referred to here. What does 'netwide' mean, and what is the alternative - i.e. what is an assembler that is *not* netwide? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what it means per-se. But my best guess is that it might be referring to the fact that it was easily accessible from the internet. This is just from a bit of thinking on my part and has no sources. I can't find any sources on the actual history of the name.

Comment: H. Peter Anvin is still active on the project. I suggest you ask on https://www.nasm.us/

Comment: @Joshua Good idea, I will! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Frank Kotler at `forum.nasm.us`:

"Netwide" essentially means that it runs on both DOS and Linux - and other platforms. When Nasm was first written, it was a big deal. Today it is common.